# Material UI CircularProgress determinate unexpected rotation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

for some reason using CircularProgress in the following way

`<CircularProgress variant="determinate" value={25} />`

renders with an unnecessary css rotation:

`transform: rotate(198.269deg);`

which looks like this:

[image]

any ideas?

Comment: Didi, you checked your `.css` files? you may find things like `snap<or some other names >{transform:rotate(198.269deg)}`

Comment: it is inline style `style="transform: rotate(198.269deg);"`. i guess generated dynamically

Comment: I have this problem too. It's not only the rotation but the length of arc is also wrong, making it not usable.